# Odd Memory Error -- Bad Alloc

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

Working on a WinPCap project. Trying to do some basic pointer and memory operations and having lots of errors.

I've included the two lines I'm trying to run along with the includes.
The same lines in another VSC++ project work just fine. This is the error I am getting

> Unhandled exception at 0x75a79617 in
>   pktdump_ex.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: std::bad_alloc at memory
>   location 0x0012f8e4..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DataTypes.h"
#include <sstream>

#include "EthernetLayer.h"

#include <pcap.h>

int* testPointer = new int[2];
delete[] testPointer;
```

EDIT:
Found out something useful.
The following code snippet is what is crashing the winpcap library.

```
EthernetStructPointers* testData;
testData = (EthernetStructPointers*)pkt_data;

EthernetStruct newData;
memcpy(newData.DEST_ADDRESS, testData->DEST_ADDRESS, 6);
```

These are the definitions of the structs.

```
struct EthernetStructPointers
{
    u_char DEST_ADDRESS[6];
    u_char SOURCE_ADDRESS[6];
    u_char TYPE[2];
};


struct EthernetStruct
{
    u_char DEST_ADDRESS[6];
    u_char SOURCE_ADDRESS[6];
    u_char TYPE[2];

    u_char* dataPointer;

    string DestAddress;
    string SourceAddress;
    string Type;

    int length;
};
```

Comment: Those two lines are fine, which is why they work in other programs. Whatever your problem is, you have trimmed it out of the post. I would suggest making the smallest possible complete reproducer and posting it.

Comment: I will try to post the code but it would require having WinPCap available.

Comment: Since you have MSVC, have you configured the debugger to break on thrown C++ exceptions and verified that the above code is the cause?

Comment: Without those lines I get no errors. With I do so I'm pretty sure they're the cause. If I set a breakpoint on them and try to step over it, I get the error.

Comment: Attach a debugger, go to Debug > Exceptions, and click the checkbox for C++ exceptions.  BTW, while you're stopped in the debugger, you can open Task Manager and see what your process's memory consumption is.

Comment: Remove everything from the code and just compile:
int main() { int* testPointer = new int[2]; delete[] testPointer; }
If it is still failing you have your cause. Otherwise, your problem is elsewhere, and you will have to narrow down your code to find where.

Comment: The memory operations fail when they are in the while loop pasted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the freestore is corrupted by one the previous statements (perhaps by an incorrect use of the pcap interface), and you only learn of the error on the next memory allocation or release, when the manager detects it and throws a bad alloc.

Comment: Solved the problem. :D
It was me trying to do a memory copy myself later on in the loop instead of using memcpy. I was pretty sure I was doing it correctly but I guess not. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

`std::bad_alloc` should be thrown when you try to `new` something and have run out of memory.  Can you check how much free memory is available to your process?

Comment: Just tried running the above a few more times. It received packet data twice then crashed with a bad alloc. How do I check how much memory is available? I am running Windows 7 with 4 gigs of RAM.

Comment: Can you open Task Manager (is there still one in Windows 7?), add as many memory-based columns as you can and re-run the test?  If any memory values spike to huge amounts it may be a clue.

Comment: Post an entire minimal code sample that produces the problem. Likely you have corrupted the heap or stack some place unrelated to the code you have shown.